# // Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value//

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

When i click on camera icon in stack widget and also it is unable to update image it show this error.It also not upload image to database nor it chaange the url** [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value E/flutter (28471): #0 _profileState.geturl (package:ecommerce/Auth/profile.dart:25:59) E/flutter (28471): **
I want to update image but facing error please solve it..

Code For Imagepicker

```
Future image(BuildContext context) async{
  showModalBottomSheet(
    elevation: 5,
    enableDrag: true,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        height: 200,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ///Gallery
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.browse_gallery),
              title: Text("Pick image from gallery"),
              onTap: () async{
                final gallery=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (gallery!=null) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text("Image Picked successfull",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  ));
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text("Please pick image for further proccess",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  ));
}
```

Code For updating Url

```
Future geturl(context)async{
  final id=DateTime.now().toString();
  final reference=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user3");
await image(context);
  final storage.Reference ref =
  storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/images'+id);
  final storage.UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image!.absolute);
  await Future.value(uploadTask);
  final  downurl=await ref.getDownloadURL();
  print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
  reference.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).update(
      {
        "imageurl":downurl.toString(),
      }
  ).then((value) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Updated successfully",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
      ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    ));
  }).catchError((e){
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("${e.message}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
      ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    ));
  });
}
```

For displaying image in flutter app

```
Stack(

                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 70,
                              backgroundImage:_image!=null?FileImage(_image!.absolute) : NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["imageurl"]) as ImageProvider,
                            ),
                             InkWell(
                                 onTap: (){
geturl(context);
                                 },
                                 child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo,size: 30,)),
                          ],
                        ),
```

***Please solve I am facing this error for Last couple of days***

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line is causing the problem:

```
final storage.UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image!.absolute);
```

Because _image is probably null. Where do you assign a value to the variable _image?

**EDIT:**

how I would fix this:

you have one method pickImage that shows the bottom modal sheet and allows the user to pick an image. if the user picks an image, you call a method that saves the picked image to firebase, in this case the method is called: saveImage

```
void pickImage(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      elevation: 5,
      enableDrag: true,
      isDismissible: false,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.browse_gallery),
                title: Text("Pick image from gallery"),
                onTap: () async {
                  XFile? pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                  if (pickedImage != null) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        "Image Picked successfull",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                      ),
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                    ));
                    var image = Image.memory(await pickedImage.readAsBytes());
                    // save image to firebase
                    saveImage(context, image);
                  } else {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        "Please pick image for further proccess",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                      ),
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                    ));
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

method that saves the image to firebase:

```
Future saveImage(context, _image) async {
    final id = DateTime.now().toString();
    final reference=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user3");
    final storage.Reference ref =
    storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/images'+id);
    final storage.UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image!.absolute);
    await Future.value(uploadTask);
    final  downurl=await ref.getDownloadURL();
    print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    reference.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).update(
        {
          "imageurl":downurl.toString(),
        }
    ).then((value) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("Updated successfully",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
        ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
      ));
    }).catchError((e){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("${e.message}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
        ),duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
      ));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Then what should i do?

Comment: I edited my previous answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the image variable null by adding "?".

Example: **DataType image?**

Then display like this

```
 image!=null ? CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 70,
                          backgroundImage: FileImage(_image!.absolute) ,
                        ): CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 70,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["imageurl"])
```

Comment: Now error in red screen Null check operator used on a null value